# RMI & RPC: functions and methods

Tags: function, methods, rmi, rpc

Reading through distributed systems, i encountered these terms and their heavy usage in the explanations of core concepts of distributed systems.

I've also looked at other questions involving the difference between a method and a function and the difference between RMI and RPC. A function always returns a value whereas a method is just a procedure. RMI uses objects to invoke methods and RPC invokes procedures at a remote system.

However, i'm not able to get a complete picture of how RMI and RPC differ in using methods and procedures to accomplish a task.

For example, as i've read in other RMI vs RPC posts, RMI is java specific and uses objects to invoke methods defined in a remote interface in a different process or computer. RPC however is used to invoke a procedure on a different system. RMI uses remote object reference which contains the IP address, port and other method id's to invoke a particular method. How is the remote procedure called in case of RPC? I mean to ask that there must be some reference to the method that you are trying to run on the remote machine. Also, access rights are easy to manage when objects are used, as in the case of RMI. How is security managed when RPC is used? A simple example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. The difference between 'function' and 'procedure' is that a function returns a value. However 'function' is usually now used to include procedures as well.
2. The difference between 'function/procedure' on the one hand and 'method' on the other hand is that a method is associated with an 'object' in an Object-Oriented Programming system.

So, RPC does remote function/procedure calls to remote systems without any concept of an object. RMI does remote method calls to a specific remote *object*.